# Do you have any comments on using GWT with Appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I'm looking for tips, suggestions, advice or examples of applications build using Google's Web Toolkit with Google AppEngine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a screencast on the subject: [Using Java (GWT) with Google App Engine](http://www.thescreencast.com/2008/04/using-java-gwt-with-google-app-engine.html)

Functionality seems very limited though since GAE uses Python + JavaScript and not Java.

Answer (score 1):

Since Google AppEngine now supports Java using GWT just became a whole lot easier (ie. you can use GWT RPC).

Take a look this [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ezm7MJeMa9M).

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate more on why using GWT with the Java version of GAE would necessarily be a good idea?

I'm not arguing against it, and it seems obvious Java would be the way to go, but just wanted to hear the concrete reasons.

To answer my own question: GWT provides an interface called "GWT RPC" that allows you to talk directly to Java Servlets, therefore offering an amazing level of integration between client and server.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the problem with GWT and GAE is that you want to use JDO to persist your objects when using GAE, and the bytecode manipulation done by the nucleus (JDO implementation) makes your domain objects no longer work with "GWT-RPC".

Today, the best solution is probably the [Gilead GWT adapter for Google App Engine](http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/index.php?page=adapter4appengine) which is currently under early stage.